# What is round box near water meter

Tags: water, water-pressure, meter, water-meter

What is round box near my water meter? I'm trying to increase the water pressure to my house, which was built in 2019. I know that the water pressure is lowered to my house and sometimes there's a water pressure regulator whose nut can be turned to increase water pressure. I tried to turn the nut on the box near the water meter (see attached image) but it won't turn. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, David

[image: Round box with nut near water meter]

[image: Round box and water meter]

Comment: There's a high likelihood that it's a cap for a clean out. Does the sewer line run near here too?

Comment: Dig it out more.  Looks more like some kind of filter, but it's not something I'm familiar with.  Since it is close to the meter, someone at the water department might be able to tell you.

Comment: What is the water pressure in  your house and how do you know it's a pressure problem vs. a flow problem?

Comment: BTW - If that device, whatever it may be, is on the water main side of the meter, it's the property of the water utility.  They will not appreciate you messing with it.